# React children[] issue with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, children

I have one component `Radio`:

```
import { RadioItemProps } from './Item';

type Props = {
  children: ReactElement<RadioItemProps>[];
};

export default function Radio(props: Props) {
  return props.children;
}
```

and a component `RadioItem` that should be a direct child of `Radio`:

```
export type RadioItemProps = {
  value: string;
  children: ReactText;
};

export default function RadioItem(props: RadioItemProps) {
  return <input type="radio" name="xxx" value={props.value} />;
}
```

When I use them:

```
<Radio>
  <RadioItem value="option-1">Option 1</RadioItem>
  <RadioItem value="option-1">Option 1</RadioItem>
</Radio>
```

I have the TypeScript error: `JSX element type 'ReactElement<RadioItemProps, ...>[]' is missing the following properties f rom type 'Element': type, props, key`

If I change the children type to `ReactElement<RadioItemProps>`, and add only one child, it works. But once I put the array, I get this error.

What I am missing?

```
"typescript": "^3.2.2",
"react": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
"@types/react": "^16.8.3",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the issue... it's because of:

```
export default function Radio(props: Props) {
  return props.children;
}
```

I had to change it to:

```
export default function Radio(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>{props.children}</Fragment>
  )
}
```

It seems that the children (typed as array) can't be returned directly. Which is strange, because this works:

```
export default function Radio(props: Props) {
  return ['lol'];
}
```

It was a tricky one...

Comment: I type my function components as [`React.FunctionComponent<Props>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L470), here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/24rwoqn00y) `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` should return a `ReactElement`.

Comment: The type checking in the sandbox.io link doesn't seem to kick in for me until I make a change, so just add and delete a line/space or something in the code.

Comment: After losing an hour trying to figure out how to properly use children prop with React.FunctionalComponent and typescript I solved the issue just by adding the fragment tags, as the FC need to return a specific type that is different from children types